# Can Eisenstein Series output complex numbers?

Tags: sequences-and-series, modular-forms

The 2nd Eisenstein Series, defined by,

$$E_{2}(\tau)=1-24\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{nq^{2n}}{1-q^{2n}},$$

where $q=e^{i\pi \tau}$ is the nome acts on upper-half plane.  Must it always output real numbers for all $\tau$?  Simple question but I can't find any info on it in the documentation online.

Comment: It's a non-constant holomorphic function on a non-empty open subset of $\mathbf{C}$, so of course it can't be real-valued.

Comment: @DavidLoeffler Makes sense, thanks.  However, can you say the output will be real on all of $\mathbb{H}$ if and only if the real part of $\tau$ is an integer?  Certainly the reverse direction is trivial, but I'm unsure of the forward direction.

Comment: @DavidLoeffler Why?  If $\rm{Re}(\tau) \in \mathbb{Z}$ doesn't all complex dependence drop out, leaving us simply with a sum over real quantities?

Comment: Sorry, my previous comment was rubbish, I've deleted it.

Comment: @DavidLoeffler No problem, thanks.  Do you think there are other values of $\tau$ for which $E_{2}$ outputs reals other that $\rm{Re}(\tau)$ either integer or half-integer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the real part of $\tau$ is an integer, then $q^2$ is a positive real.
If the real part of $\tau$ is a half-integer, then $q^2$ is a negative real.
In both cases, $\operatorname{E}_2(\tau)$ must be real.

Due to $\operatorname{E}_2$ being holomorphic,
infinitesimal deviations from those vertical rays $2\Re\tau\in\mathbb{Z}$
result in non-real changes to $\operatorname{E}_2(\tau)$ whenever $\frac{\mathrm{d}\!\operatorname{E}_2(\tau)}{\mathrm{d}\tau}\neq0$.

Nevertheless, there are more curves beside the above vertical rays
where $\operatorname{E}_2(\tau)$ is real.

The plot below, together with a colormap, shows 
$\operatorname{E}_2(\tau)$ for $\Re\tau\in[-\frac{3}{2},+\frac{3}{2}],
\Im\tau\in(0,\frac{15}{8}]$.
The colormap ignores magnitude and quantizes polar angles into $24$ bins.

[image][image]

Accordingly, the curves where $\operatorname{E}_2(\tau)$ is real
are the boundaries between the magenta and fully saturated red regions (for positive values) and the boundaries between brightest cyan and light greenish tints (for negative values). The curves split at points where
$\frac{\mathrm{d}\!\operatorname{E}_2(\tau)}{\mathrm{d}\tau}=0$.
The color vortex points mark simple zeros (in the plane) resp. double poles
(on the real axis).

Comment: Very helpful plots; thanks!  However, do they imply that the realness of $E_{2}$ breaks down for very small $\rm{Im}(\tau)$ even when the real part is integer of half-integer?  It seems that the curves bordering magenta and red signaling real $E_{2}$ disappear when we come to those large "heart shaped" regions.  I don't see how this can happen.

Comment: Cannot happen; the vertical rays just change to green/cyan for small $\Im\tau$, which signifies negative real values of $\operatorname{E}_2(\tau)$.

Comment: I'm curious if $d E_{2}(\tau)/d \tau$ has similar behavior?  That is, will it output real values when $\rm{Re}(\tau)$ is integer or half-integer?

Comment: For $q=\exp(2\pi\mathrm{i}\tau)$, $q\frac{\mathrm{d}E_2}{\mathrm{d}q} = \frac{1}{2\pi\mathrm{i}}\,\frac{\mathrm{d}E_2}{\mathrm{d}\tau}$ will be real if $2\Re\tau\in\mathbb{Z}$. This means that $\frac{\mathrm{d}E_2}{\mathrm{d}\tau}$ will be purely imaginary there. Intuitively, if something is real along a vertical ray, this means that purely imaginary steps result in purely real changes, hence the derivative is purely imaginary.

Comment: Hi, may I ask what you used for making these plots? They look lovely.

Comment: @Guesswhoitis.: Customized FreeMat or Octave code. Of course, one needs to implement the function for $E_2$ first. For $\Im\tau<\frac{1}{2}$, reduce $\Re\tau\bmod{1}$, then transform to $\frac{-1}{\tau}$. Repeat until $\Im\tau$ is large enough. Then use the $q$-series. (I have been worrying about loss of relative accuracy for large $\Re\frac{-1}{\tau}$ and tried to take more sophisticated routes, but it turns out that this is not worth the effort.)

Comment: I see; I had used the formula relating $E_2$ and the complete elliptic integral of the second kind (from Abramowitz and Stegun), but wound up with a function that inherited the branch cuts of $E(m)$; I'll test your route the next time I have a computer…

Comment: @Guesswhoitis.: The half-period increments $\eta_1,\eta_2$ of Weierstrass's $\zeta$ (negative antiderivative of $\wp$) are also related to $E_2$. And I have occasionally run into trouble with branches of the complete elliptic integrals too. :-)

Comment: @ccorn, I finally got around to implementing your suggested algorithm. [It does look lovely.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0nkGa.png)

Comment: @J.M.isn'tamathematician: Looks fine to me, if that plot is $E_2$ in terms of $q=\exp(\pi\mathrm{i}\tau)$, as in this thread. I typically use $q=\exp(2\pi\mathrm{i}\tau)$ for Eisenstein series, so all the exponents in the series do not need that explicit factor 2. The result is that my Eisenstein plots are not point-symmetric, the right bulge being the largest, [like that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iskmT.png).

Comment: Yes, I used $q$ instead of $q^2$ as the independent variable for that domain coloring plot. I'm just glad it works now. :)